# SQLServerCE / Local Data Cache / Sync Framework - Insert Error

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-ce, microsoft-sync-framework

Hopefully someone can help me. I have a Visual  Studio 2008 WinForms 
application to which I have added a Local Data Cache. The local data cache is 
using a SDF file via SqlServerCE and is caching a SQL Server 2008 dbase with 
change tracking enabled.

This is working and I can do bidirectional syncs and the like.

The problem I am having is with inserting data in to the local tables that 
have been created by the VS wizards. When I try insert data either 
programmatically or even through the VS interface (show data) I get a error 
stating ***“A duplicate value cannot be inserted into a unique index”*** due to a 
primary key constraint.

The tables have a auto inc int primary key and it seems like the seed has 
been reset back to one. This doesn’t happen to all the tables though, only a 
few.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Regards,
Adam

Answer (score 0):

- can you post the Server DDL Statement for the relevant table?

  - How are you creating the primary keys on the client? The error Message says you are trying to insert the same PrimaryKey again in the table.
  - Maybe also consider [sqlce does not support server generated keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648449/server-generated-keys-and-server-generated-values-are-not-supported-by-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, and replaced Int/auto-incremental values with GUIDs. works good for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by making each primary key on each of my tables a `GUID`. This way, when records are created on the client in an offline environment, and then synced back with the server, there are no conflicts between the client/server primary keys. This also prevents conflicts with the `IDENTITY` attributed being auto incremented on each `INSERT` to a value that already exists.

As seen in the below screenshot, the Data Type is set to `nvarchar(50)` (it can be any string-like Data Type), the Default Value is set to `(newid())`, and the Identity Specification is set to `No`.

GUID attribute screenshot in SQL Server Management Studio:
[image: GUID attribute screenshot in SQL Server Management Studio]

You can read more about the `GUID` Data Type from [Microsoft's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726011(v=sql.110).aspx), and see if they're appropriate for your particular scenario.